# How to print all data of one column of sqldatareader in many labels?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm selecting data from a database into a `SqlDataReader`. When trying to populate the data in some labels I noticed that all of the labels display the same value, because the `SqlDataReader` has only one column with many values.

How can I display those values ??

Here is my code:

[image]

Comment: Code can speak more than words, please include the snippets

Comment: i put it but it didn't show off i don't know why ? the stored retrieves one column with 3 rows

Comment: Please add the real code to the question, adding a picture of the code is not helpful and make the question much harder to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the data in `SqlDataReader` can be like a matrix, it depends on the query. The next snippet shows you how you can get each "cell" in your `SqlDataReader`:

```
//This "while" iterates through all rows!
while(MysqlData.Read())
{   
    //This "for" iterates through each column of the current row!
    for (int i = 0; i < MysqlData.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        lRoom.Add(MysqlData.GetValue(i).ToString());
    }
}
```

MysqlData is our `SqlDataReader`.

The row with the lRoom.Add... is the place where you can do the printing you have asked for!